# Looping through a list to fill in missing dates (with NAs or 0s in R

Tags: r, date

I am working with a dataset that has dates over multiple IDs. For each ID my goal is to have full years worth of data for however long that ID appears in my dataset. The issue is between all of my IDs I have ~4 continuous years worth of data even though I might have one ID that does not contribute a continuous year.

I am hoping to loop through each ID value and use the complete function to fill in the dates that that ID specifically is missing, or even identify the Date and ID that is missing from the dataset I have tried this two ways:

```
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2004/01/01"), as.Date("2020/12/31"), "days"), each=20)
Animal_id <- rep(1:20, times=length(unique(dates)))
df <- data.frame(dates=dates, id=Animal_id)
df[,"Year"]<-format(df[,"dates"],"%Y")
df <- df[-4, ]
df <- df[-6, ]
df <- df[-10, ]
df <- df[-15, ]
df <- df[-16, ]
df <- df[-20, ]
##Take out random columns
##split the data 
x<-split(df,df$Animal_id)

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  complete(Date=seq.Date(min(dates),max(dates),by="day"))
}
```

which produces this error:

Error in min(Date) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

My goal is to be able to have NAs for each missing ID and date so I can then look at what IDs have an NA for that missing date.

I have also tried to figure out which IDs were missing specific dates using a loop through the following method:

```
df$combo<-paste(df$Animal_id,df$Year, sep = "-")
z<-split(df, df$combo)

missingID<-(NULL)

for (i in 1:length(z)){
  AnimalIDloop<-z[[i]]
  myDataDateID<-AnimalIDloop[,c("dates")]
  FullSeqID<-seq.Date(from = min(myDataDateID), to=max(myDataDateID), by=1)
  missingID<-rbind((FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% myDataDateID]),AnimalIDloop$Animal_id[2])
  
  ##rbind dataframe created with the column being AnimalID, Other columns = ##second part  
  ##pull out first value from the AnimalID column 
  
  ##missingID<-rbind(MissingID, new rows (above))
}
missingID
```

Essentially I am trying to use the Rbind function to create a new dataframe with each of the missing dates, taking the first value from the animal ID column. My goal is to have the ID listed, as well as the date that is missing for that ID ( if an ID is missing multiple days then it would appear multiple times for each date), but the above does not give me the output I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Edit- I was using the split function and loop because in my dataset not all animal ids appear in every year (i.e. some individuals die or are no longer monitored) I am just trying to ensure that each id has a full year of data for the year that it appears in.

Comment: Does `tidyr::complete(df, date, id)` do what you're looking for? This will complete all combinations of `date` and `id` found in `df` leaving `NA` in the other columns. You can identify missing combinations by filter for NA values in `Year` in your example.

Comment: Unfortunately because each id in my dataset is not in the dataset for the entire duration of the study this does not work- i.e. I have some animals that die, While this works if I were to have the same ids throughout my entire study, it also fills in all the IDs that do not appear in certain years with NAs

Comment: Do you want complete dates for every year that an animal lived (i.e., if the animal dies in November, would you still want the dates from December of the same year and none thereafter)? Or do you only want complete dates between the first and last measurements for an animal (i.e., die in November and no further dates)? May I ask why you want to complete the dates for which there were no measurements?

Comment: Hi Will! I am really just looking for a way to know what animals are MISSING dates throughout the year i.1. a collar did not record a location for that day, versus the animal died. I cannot figure out a way to loop through the whole dataset to get R to tell me what animal is missing data on what dates within the years that it was alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you find your answer.

In this first part, I created some new example data with missing measurements for two animals that were born and died within the same calendar year.

```r
fake_measurements <- function(dates, n, birth, death) {
  x <- sample(dates, n)
  x <- x[x >= birth & x <= death]
  x[order(x)]
}

dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2022/01/01"), as.Date("2022/12/31"), "days"))
birth = c(A = "2022-02-01", B = "2022-04-01")
death = c(A = "2022-10-01", B = "2022-09-01")

measurements <- 
  purrr::pmap(
  list(birth, death), 
  fake_measurements, 
  dates = dates, 
  n = 200
)

df <- 
  tibble::enframe(measurements) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(value)) %>%
  dplyr::rename(id = name, date = value)
```

Using your initial approach, you have split your original data by animal ID and so I wrote a function `find_missing_measurements` that will take your data frame from one animal and the list of all measurement dates, find the minimum and maximum measurements for a given animal indicating the period of their life, and then return the values of missing dates from that interval. An `lapply` then iterates over your list of data frames.

```r
dates <- unique(df$date)
animals <- split(df, df$id)

find_missing_measurements <- function(df, dates) {
  possible_dates_while_alive <- dates[dates >= min(df$date) & dates <= max(df$date)]
  possible_dates_while_alive[!(possible_dates_while_alive %in% df$date)]
}

lapply(animals, find_missing_measurements, dates)
```